# Issue with :last-child on a list item Menu

Tags: html, css

Here's my updated JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/axosonns/2/

HTML:

```
<ul class="whatever">
  <li><a href="#">Menu1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu4</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.whatever li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.whatever li>a {
  background: grey;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}
.whatever li>a:last-child {
  padding: 10px 0 10px 15px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

The last-child css code isn't working. I want only the last menu to have `padding: 0px;`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is this what you want? https://jsfiddle.net/qLauktnm/

Comment: No. but thank you. I got the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a little unclear. If you're trying to make the whole colored-background area clickable, you were on the right track - use padding on the `a`, not the `li`. You can still target the one you need, just tweak the selectors a little. [Here's a fork with that.](https://jsfiddle.net/oqv6m1qn/)

```css
.whatever li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.whatever li a {
  background: grey;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}
.whatever li:last-child a {
  padding: 10px 0 10px 15px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="whatever">
  <li><a href="#">Menu1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

you selected last element of `a` in each `li` , 
you have to select last `li` element and target `a` in that

`.whatever li>a:last-child`   to this `.whatever li:last-child a`

```css
.whatever li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.whatever li>a {
  background: grey;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}
.whatever li:last-child a{
  padding: 10px 15px 10px 15px;
  /* padding: 0px; */
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="whatever">
  <li><a href="#">Menu1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu4</a></li>
</ul>
```